# Client app calls an azure function with Azure AD but results as 401 unauthorized

Tags: azure

I am trying to secure my Azure function app using Azure AD. I am hitting my Function App URL using Postman with Bearer Token.

Function url Format as : https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/function-name?queryparameter
I have ClientId, ClientSecret and Tenant.
I generated the Bearer Token.
I have passed the Bearer Token as the Authorization header to my function app.
Still I am getting 401 Unauthoreized.

Comment: Could you please share your code that would be easier.

Comment: I followed the instruction from  https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/authenticate-an-azure-function-with-azure-active-directory/


I generated the Bearer token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token  through Postman

Comment: Did you add API permission on your your azure portal?

Comment: really hard to help you, but review the audience for the application on your Azure AD as well the API permissions

Comment: Thanks for the help guyss.... After some digging, i got th solution. The steps I followed were correct but in my function app that I published, the AuthorizationLevel was Function. All I had to do is make it Anonymous. And, it worked!!